# Ошибка при загрузке изображений/документов через Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, paperclip

Добрый день, я столкнулся с ошибкой, что при загрузке изображений на S3 через `Paperclip` я получаю ошибку `has an extension that does not match its contents`. На локальной машине такие проблемы не испытываю, только на продакшен. Такое стал наблюдать после обновления рельсов `4.1.1 -> 4.1.16` и `ruby 2.1.5 -> 2.3.1` и смены инстанса на `AWS` .

Вот моя валидация:

```
validates_attachment    :document,
                        content_type: { not: "application/x-msdownload" }
```

не понимаю в чем проблема. Любой файл загружаю, будь то изображение или документ(любого расширения) получаю эту ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

**UPD**

в логах нашел вот эту строку

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename example1.png (["image/png"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

Comment: В логе ещё должна быть строчка с `content type discovered from file command`.

Comment: @D-side нет строчки в логах.

Comment: Значит, уровень логов недостаточно разговорчивый. Выясните, какой content type он обнаруживает для ваших файлов.

Comment: @D-side нашел эту строчку в логах. Обновил вопрос

Comment: @D-side в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Похоже, что со сменой инстанса вы получили утилиту `file`, ведущую себя совсем иначе и ничего не распознающую.

Comment: @D-side подскажи пожалуйста, как фиксить такую проблему?